# differentiating a complex function $f=z\bar{z}$ w.r.t. $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $z$ is a complex number, what is the derivative $df/dz$, where $f=z\bar{z}$? The straight differentiation gives me $df/dz=\bar{z}+z(d\bar{z}/dz)$. Here,

$d\bar{z}/dz = \lim_{\Delta z\rightarrow 0} \frac{\overline{z+\Delta z}-\bar{z}}{\Delta z}=\ldots = \lim_{\Delta z\rightarrow 0} \frac{\overline{\Delta z}}{\Delta z}$

If I take $\Delta z$ as real, then this last limit is one and $df/dz=z + \bar{z} = 2\,{\rm Re}(z)$. If I take $\Delta z$ as imaginary, this limit is -1 and then $df/dz = \bar{z}-z=-2\,{\rm Im}(z)$. It looks as if the function $f$ is not differentiable, am I correct?

Just to show you what I need. I have a function $F=\int_V \left[A\phi^2({\bf r}) d{\bf r}+\ldots\right]\,dV$ that I need to transform into the Fourier space (there are extra terms that don't allow me to stay in real space). By the Parseval's identity, the function above is $F=\int_\Omega \left[A|\tilde\phi({\bf k})|^2+\ldots\right]\, d{\bf k}$. Now, I need to differentiate the integrand w.r.t. $\tilde\phi({\bf k})$ which leads to the problem above. Is there any trick that would help here or I am wrong completely?

Comment: You may be looking for the Wirtinger derivatives, $\partial/\partial z$ and $\partial/\partial\overline{z}$.

Comment: Thank you, I tried both. They give $z$ or $\bar{z}$, depending on which of them I use.

Comment: Right. Whether you want the Wirtinger derivatives depends on what you want to do. Unfortunately, I have no idea what that is.

Answer (score 4):

From the context you have given in comments, it is clear that you need to treat $z$ and $\bar z$ as independent variables, i.e.
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(z\bar z) = \bar z ~,~ \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}(z\bar z) = z
$$

As has already been pointed out, $df/dz$ only makes sense for holomorphic $f$.

In general, when you are looking for stationary points of action functionals, you need to vary with respect to $\phi$ and $\bar \phi$ independently -- this is equivalent to varying the real and imaginary parts of $\phi$ independently.

Comment: Thanks Rhys. I remember doing something like this in my field theory class. I am looking at it now.

Answer (score 3):

This function is not complex-differentiable for any $z\in \mathbb{C}$. By the open mapping theorem, an analytic function which is nonconstant sends open sets to open sets. The image of $f(z) = |z|^2$ is always real, and no subset $S\subset \mathbb{C}$ composed entirely of real numbers can be open. Since $f$ is not constant, it cannot be analytic in any open set.

Comment: Yes, this is what I think too. However, the integral that I mention is quite frequent in classical field theory (Landau-Ginzburg) and people differentiate it (somehow).

Comment: I clarified it a bit more. I'm not familiar with the material you mention, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you, Eric. I got the message. I will try to write below a bit more to highlight the problem that I have.

Comment: Here is what I have exactly:

$F = \int_\Omega \left[A|\tilde\phi_1({\bf k})|^2 + B|\tilde\phi_2({\bf k})|^2 + \Lambda \tilde{g}[\tilde\phi_1({\bf k}),\tilde\phi_2({\bf k})] \right]~d\Omega$.

Here, $\tilde{g}$ is a constraint for the two fields and $\Lambda$ is a Lagrange multiplier. To get the stationary values of the two fields, I do $\delta F/\delta \tilde\phi_{1}({\bf k})=0$, $\delta F/\delta \tilde\phi_{2}({\bf k})=0$ and $\delta F/\delta \Lambda=0$. What can I do with the two squared moduli of the fields?

Comment: I would add this to your question, or better yet, post a separate question specifically about this. Make sure to tag it with "optimization" or other relevant fields.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  These will tell you that the conjugacy map $z\mapsto{\overline z}$ and even the square of the absolute value map $z\mapsto |z|^2$ are not analytic.

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out, this function is nowhere analytic. However, is it differentiable at $0$ and this is the only point where it is so. It's one of those strange-case functions that's differentiable at isolated points.